# Always approach the maximum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code where I get the most approximate value from an array. But I want to get only the highest value. What I want to say if I enter the value `760` this should bring me the value `800` not the value `750`.

```js
validate_ancho(760);

function validate_ancho(this_ancho) {

  var x = this_ancho;
  var array = [600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 900, 950, 1000];
  var closest = array.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(x - a) - Math.abs(x - b))[0];
  var ancho_validate = closest - this_ancho;

  console.log(ancho_validate);

  if (ancho_validate > 20) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Always get the value from above, never down. Hope I explain well. Greetings

Comment: I turned the code into a runnable snippet but I'm not sure what you'd normally call it with. Do you expect to do something like `validate_ancho(760)` and get `800` back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the first item matching a predicate. Here the predicate is keep the first item greater than x.

We use [Array.prototyp.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

> The `find()` method returns the **value** of the **first element** in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise `undefined` is returned.

```js
// we take a number as input and we output the closet higher number in the array
function validate_ancho(this_ancho) {
  const array = [600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 900, 950, 1000];
  const closest = array.find(x => x >= this_ancho);

  return closest;
}

console.log(validate_ancho(760))
```

Comment: This only works if the array is sorted in ascending order.

Comment: @ShortFuse Indeed.

Answer (score 3):

You are sorting by distance and get the item with the smallest distance. For getting a slightly smaller value, you need to find this value in an ascending sorted array.

```js
function validate_ancho(x) {
  var array = [600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 900, 950, 1000],
      closest = array.find(v => v >= x) || array[array.length - 1],
      ancho_validate = closest - x;

  console.log(closest);
  return ancho_validate > 20;
}

console.log(validate_ancho(760));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also filter the array

```js
validate_ancho(760);

function validate_ancho(this_ancho) {

  var x = this_ancho;
  var array = [600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 900, 950, 1000];
  var closest = array.filter(function(z){ return z > x;}).sort((a, b) => Math.abs(x - a) - Math.abs(x - b))[0];
  var ancho_validate = closest - this_ancho;

  console.log(ancho_validate);

  if (ancho_validate > 20) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why filter the whole array when you can stop when you have the match with `find`

Comment: @aloisdg, this is just another way to accomplish the same end goal. Not necessarily the best way, but another option that may help either the question author or another user in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your algorithm is wrong. The code you posted is picking the value with the lowest absolute value. Therefore, it's the closest.

What you're asking for is the closest value that's not less than the input variables.

So filter out the values that are higher than x.

```
validate_ancho(760);

function validate_ancho(this_ancho) {

  var x = this_ancho;
  var array = [600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 900, 950, 1000];
  var closest = array.filter(a => a > x).sort((a, b) => a - b)[0];
  var ancho_validate = closest - this_ancho;

  console.log(ancho_validate);

  if (ancho_validate > 20) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use `Array.reduce` in one shot:

```
closest = array.reduce((acc, cur) => cur > x && (acc == null || cur < acc) ? cur : acc, null)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let array = [600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 900, 950,1000];
let myNumber = 960;
let closest = array.filter((el) => el > myNumber)[0];
console.log(closest)
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you have to filter the whole array first. `find` is the way to go here.